# Good examples of prototypal inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im learning javascript after spending years getting along with using jquery and not really understanding the underlying language properly.

Coming more from a classical oop background im finding prototypal inheritance in js a little difficult to get going with.

I just keep finding myself wanting to use constructor functions as they feel more natural.

I mean for sure, I understand the concept but im finding it difficult to put it in to real practice and I think getting over this will improve my learning greatly.

Can anyone offer some examples - github or otherwise - of projects doing this correctly?

Comment: here there are good examples: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: After the link of @Paolo you can check the John Resig implementation of prototypal Inheritance : http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/